# Struts-Layout table heading with unwanted characters

Tags: java, struts

I am using struts-layout 1.4 to draw an editable table. All is well except the table heading part. Each heading in the table contain ???en_US. as shown below. I've tried to add a filter and set "content-type" but in vain. ???en_US. is not part of my code neither in any JSP nor java class. Please help to remove these from headings.

```
???en_US.Name???  ???en_US.Department??? ???en_US.Designation???

John            Java                   SSE
```

Comment: You are missing resources, those are the keys of the missing messages.

Comment: Instead of prefixing resources, create resource bundles for the specific locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments of your question, you need to create the right the right resource bundle corresponding to the locale. `???en_US.Name???` means that struct cannot find the value of `Name` for the `en_US` locale.

You can get some info about this [here](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/struts/05-Struts-Messages.pdf).